# Где правильнее обрабатывать события?

Tags: javascript, html, события, веб-программирование, best-practice

Есть две страницы и файл *script.js*, который подключен к этим страницам.

*index*:

```
<button id="index">index</button>
```

*str*:

```
<button id="str">str</button>
```

Мне нужно обрабатывать нажатия на кнопки. Как будет правильнее это сделать?

1. В конце каждой страницы написать `<script>`, и в нём повесить обработчик события.
2. В конце каждой страницы написать `<script>`, и в нём прописать только функцию, а в атрибут `onclick` у `button` написать название функции.
3. В *script.js* прописать функции, а в атрибуты `onclick` у `button` написать название функции.
4. Полностью вешать обработчик события в *script.js*, и в нём же событие и обрабатывать.

Примеры:

[1 - первый](http://jsfiddle.net/jg4nk0yb/)

[2 - второй](http://jsfiddle.net/uxhkd3xs/1/)

[3 - третий](http://jsfiddle.net/zsh7sLvw/)

[4 - четвёртый](http://jsfiddle.net/3L3tq98q/)

В примерах `<hr>` разделяет страницы. А всё, что написано в JavaScript, считается вынесенным в *script.js*.

---

Смысл заключается в том, что если будет много страниц и вешать обработчики в *script.js*, то на открытой странице в *script.js* будут прописаны обработчики событий и других страниц. Получится, что большая часть *script.js* загружается, но не используется на странице.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В современных веб-проектах кофеином и нервами разработчиков выработался следующий подход: отделять друг от друга структуру вебстраницы (HTML), оформление (CSS) и поведение (javascript). Поэтому если вкратце, то правильный путь - четвертый.

Это правило имеет смысл нарушать только в каких-нибудь вырожденных случаях и учебных заданиях, в мало-мальски серьезных проектах делают в основном так. Случаи когда нам действительно могут пригодиться инлайновые скрипты есть, но они редки. Вероятно это какой-нибудь хайлоад, где нам надо экономить запросы.

Обработчики событий относятся к поведению страницы. Навешивание инлайновых обработчиков (то есть прописывание их прямо в коде элемента) считается ужасно плохим стилем. Правильно прикреплять их в javascript коде с помощью `addEventListener`, `attachEvent` (если приходится работать со старыми ослами) или соответствующие методы библиотеки, как делаете Вы в примере.

Чем такой способ организации страниц лучше, чем "все в одном"?

1. В первую очередь поддержка. Когда у вас отдельно скрипты отдельно html - это сопровождать в разы легче. Легче отлаживать с помощью инструментов разработки, легче понимать что ты именно можешь задеть своими изменениям.
2. Разделение труда. Когда js отдельно, хтмл и стили отдельно, то программист может спокойно думать над высокоуровневыми абстракциями а не над тем что там менюшка на два пикселя влево съехала. Верстальщик же может спокойно делать красиво, не опасаясь что ему программист в dom наложит.
3. Кеширование и внутренние оптимизации. Инлайновые обработчики нарушают множество внутренних механизмов кеширования и оптимизации браузеров. То есть если Вы отделите js от html и css то в среднем у вас все будет быстрее работать.
4. Инлайновые скрипты делают код куда более уязвимым к xss-атакам. Ну это как вишенка на торте.

По поводу того, что вас беспокоит подключение лишних скриптов к странице:

1. Вам не обязательно иметь один файл script.js. Вы можете описать общую логику страниц в одном файле скриптов, специфичную логику - в других.
2. Если судить по уровню вопроса, то в вашем случае это наверняка экономия на спичках. Есть большие и сложные  приложения, в которых это играет роль. Тогда js-код бьется на модули, которые подгружаются когда нужно, с использованием [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs) например. Плюс код минифицируется. Но это уже кейс "сложное spa приложение" а не кейс "landing page Васи Пупкина", и требует отдельного большого поста.